# Java Swing JTable select programmatically multiple rows

Tags: java, swing, jtable, row, selection

I have a JTable with multiple rows and every row is presented via Point on a scatter plot. What I have to do is when a given point is selected on the scatter plot I have to associate this selection with selecting of the corresponding row in the JTable.

I have an Integer that represents, which row I have to highlight.

What I tried is:

```
    JTable table = new JTable();
...
...// a bit of code where I have populated the table
...
   table.setRowSelectionInterval(index1,index2);
```

So the problem here is that this method selects all rows in the given range [index1,index2]. I want to select for example rows 1,15,28,188 etc.

How do you do that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To select just one row, pass it as both the start and end index:

```
table.setRowSelectionInterval(18, 18);
```

Or, if you want to select multiple, non-contiguous indices:

```
ListSelectionModel model = table.getSelectionModel();
model.clearSelection();
model.addSelectionInterval(1, 1);
model.addSelectionInterval(18, 18);
model.addSelectionInterval(23, 23);
```

Alternately, you may find that implementing your own subclass of `ListSelectionModel` and using it to track selection on both the table and the scatterplot is a cleaner solution, rather than listening on the scatterplot and forcing the table to match.

Comment: Aha that's what I have just tried and it seems that works fine for me : ) Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

It also works without using the ListSelectionModel:

```
table.clearSelection();
table.addRowSelectionInterval(1, 1);
table.addRowSelectionInterval(15, 15);
table.addRowSelectionInterval(28, 28);
...
```

Just don't call the setRowSelectionInterval, as it always clears the current selection before.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to set a random selection with a one method call, you need more than one to perform this kind of selection

```
table.setRowSelectionInterval(1, 1);
table.addRowSelectionInterval(15, 15);
table.setRowSelectionInterval(28, 28);
table.addRowSelectionInterval(188 , 188 );
```

And So On....

Comment: @Jäbir after this just last line will be selected. you need to use `ListSelectionModel` as pointed in [post above](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15556376/1196670)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a generic method to accomplish this:

```
public static void setSelectedRows(JTable table, int[] rows)
{
    ListSelectionModel model = table.getSelectionModel();
    model.clearSelection();

    for (int row : rows)
    {
        model.addSelectionInterval(row, row);
    }
}
```